# unable to start notebook on python linux server

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have installed anaconda on linux. I am trying to bring up jupyter notebook as follows:

```
./jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889
```

looks like it starts, no errors on the console. But when I try to access the url

```
http://<server ip>:8889
```

I get page unavailable error. Any ideas what I am missing here?

this is the output after starting the jupyter notebook:

```
 bin]$ ./jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889
[I 15:43:02.760 NotebookApp] JupyterLab beta preview extension loaded from /usr/local/clo/ven/python-2.7.12/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 15:43:02.760 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/clo/ven/python-2.7.12/anaconda2/share/jupyter/lab
[I 15:43:02.765 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /usr/local/clo/ven/python-2.7.12/anaconda2/bin
[I 15:43:02.765 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 15:43:02.766 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 15:43:02.766 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8889/?token=e2d0598937406066fc34f23f5f2187f2d6393976d84b5a2e
[I 15:43:02.766 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 15:43:02.766 NotebookApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8889/?token=e2d0598937406066fc34f23f5f2187f2d6393976d84b5a2e&token=e2d0598937406066fc34f23f5f2187f2d6393976d84b5a2e
```

Comment: Sometimes it helps to double check the server ip is accesible.  On a command line you can double check by using  `ping <server ip>`

Comment: I can ping the ip.

Comment: Did you try with full token ? For example:         

http://localhost:8889/?token=e2d0598937406066fc34f23f5f2187f2d6393976d84b5a2e&token=e2d0598937406066fc34f23f5f2187f2d6393976d84b5a2e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, a notebook server runs locally at 127.0.0.1:8888 and is accessible only from localhost. You may access the notebook server from the browser using http://127.0.0.1:8888; this means you can't access it from the outer world (which is any machine except the server)

to change it follow the instruction in the [official docs](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html)

in case the above instructions didn't work, you can forward your ip address so it is considered somehow as part of the server:

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 remote_user@remote_host
```